# Effcient merge strategy for Live project after/while refactoring and re structuring code

Tags: java, android, architecture, refactoring, merge-conflict-resolution

**What I have**

1. V2 android project that is **live** and **in maintenance** by different team . This project get lots of bug fixes committed.
2. V3 project(**not live**) -This is  branched from V2 project & minor code refracting and restructuring is done in such a way- that when we merge latest v2 code the conflicts are easily resolved.

**What I need to do**

3. V2 project is a [big ball of mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud) which has high coupling. I need to do major restructuring, decoupling  and modify architecture in V3 project (further version for v2 project )

**What challenge I will face**

We need to regularly pull latest code form V2 and merge into V3. If we drastically change the code after refactoring it, merging the code will become a big problem , as the project is large & its impossible to remember which v2 code will correspond to V3 code.

**What I have in mind**
I was thinking of having some sort of index/mapping - which will tell which V2 code maps to V3 code. But this approach does not seem very feasible and efficient as the project is huge. I did not find many solutions  online yet.

> I need help regarding -which approach/technique I can follow to make
> the merging of code efficient and easy (in such a way all project
> developers know which code will merge where , easily)